# How to change multiple file names in the same format with git on Windows 10?

Tags: git, mv

I have hundreds of files called `tutorial_xx.cpp`, where `xx` is a number from 1 to 99. I reached the three-digit mark, and now I have to change all the file numbers so that I can keep track of chronological order. I was thinking that, if I can add a `0` between `tutorial_` and `xx.cpp` I could achieve this, but apparently this didn't work:

```
git mv tutorial_*.cpp tutorial_0*.cpp
```

Is it possible to successfully do such a thing in git? And if so, how?

Comment: You can also locally rename the files with any bulk tool approperiate, git will figure the renames out based on the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If in git-bash, you could try:

```
for name in tutorial_*.cpp;do
    git mv $name ${name/_/_0/}
done
```

If you have Python installed, try:

```
python -c "import os;map(lambda x:os.rename(x,x.replace('_','_0',1)),filter(lambda x:'tutorial_' in x, os.listdir('.')))"
```